# Working with SSAS cubes with limited rights and dataset size in power bi

Tags: powerbi, ssas, cube

So I'm working on Power BI reports. Since the datasets are huge ( we have a power bi PRO plan, not premium ) we are using live connection to SSAS cubes for our reports. For others to see the data in these reports I have to set up a gateway. For live connection personal mode gateway does not work. For on premises gateway I need admin rights for that cube which they will not give me.

1st question: Is there a way I could analyse that cube and see its connections without having admin access to that cube? ( read only ) So I could maybe ignore cube and make a direct query to DW where I can make a gateway to.

2nd question: We have our own server aswell where I have admin rights, so maybe there is a way I could copy the cube into our server like pulling data directly from that cube to a cube in our own servers? ( Since I dont have admin rights to the original cube I cant just backup and restore it )

3rd question: Maybe there is another way or a trick to set up a gateway so other users with power bi pro licence but without access to the cube could see the data?

I'm open to any solutions or hints.

In short I just need to make reports from huge datasets while being limited to 1GB only.

Comment: you don't need admin rights to connect the data gateway to the cube, just an account that can use it.

Comment: @Jon When I try to add the cube to gateway: Underlying error message: The 'xxxx' user does not have permission to call the Discover method.
Discover method requires administrative access to Analysis services.